# What is "Dummy for Loop" in C?

Tags: c

One of my friend asked me this question while we were travelling back to home. And he got to know about this from his teacher. First he told me its something like the infinite loop with no body. Hence I posted this question here asking whether ***infinite loop*** is called as dummy for loop.

I haven't seen anything like Dummy For in any of the books I read and not from the internet as well. Later he told me that those for loops which contains blank body are known as dummy loop. One like this :

```
for (int i=0; i<10; ++i);
```

Such loops are quite helpful in some cases. I was more eager to know if there is something really exists in software development field or it's just a name given by an individual.

Sorry for the delay in editing the details.

Comment: This is an infinite loop.

Comment: Sometimes used in embedded systems when a fatal error has occurred and you want to idle the software until the watchdog timer resets the system.

Comment: can you give an hint of the trigger of your question ? Where did you hit that code ? this is an active infinite loop, what is something we would normaly try to avoid.

Comment: I just heard it form one of my friend, he asked me this. I answered him that it is an infinite loop that is used in OS, Games, Micricontrollers and much more but then also I put forward this question here to know more about it !

Answer (score 4):

It is an infinite loop with no body. The purpose would be to make sure the program doesn't end, yet does nothing. It is also known as an idle loop.

That doesn't mean nothing will ever happen. There could still be interrupts occurring, which make the cpu jump out of the loop, and return to the loop after the interrupt service routine has finished.

Often this technique is used in embedded programming, where inputs and timers trigger interrupts, in which all of the activity occurs. When no interrupt is being serviced, we want to ensure the program doesn't just run off the end of the code.

Comment: It usually have as [side effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect) to heat the computer. You might want some [idle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idle_%28CPU%29) loop instead.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks for your suggestion. Edited the answer to include this term.

Comment: No, `for(;;)` is not an idle loop it is a buzy burning loop; but `for(;;) sigsuspend(NULL);` is an idle loop (with the real processing in signals or interrupts handlers)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch `sigsuspend()` is a system call for Linux only. It is not part of the C language. While it is true that idle loops may incorporate some kind of sleep (dependent on the processor), but they don't have to. The original question is what `for(;;);` can be used for.

Comment: Agree, but my point was that an *idle* loop is around some ["idle" instruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idle_%28CPU%29) which pauses the processor (so uses less energy than a buzy loop)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yes, but a busy loop or busy-waiting loop is something else. A busy loop checks a condition to see if it should exit. An idle loop has no such check. "Idling" is an analogy that comes from a gasoline-powered car; the engine is wasting fuel while the car sits still. Electric cars that don't use energy while stopped are clearly more efficient, but that is because they are not idling.

Answer (score 1):

Infinite loop. This keeps running the `for` loop forever.
Just to mention the use of it.There might be a need where the user keeps inputting some data and when some particular match is found you need to break out of this.

Similar to

```
while(1)
{
}
```

Example:

```
while(1)
{
    printf("Enter a number\n");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    flag = 0;
    switch(a)
    {
        case 1:
        printf("hi\n");
        break;
        case 2:
        flag = 1;
        break;
    }
    if(flag)
    break;
}
printf("Out of while loop\n");
}
```

Comment: Except that it has no body and thus has no mechanism to `break` as you explain and show in your example.

Answer (score 1):

The loop you described **for( ; ; );** is an infinite loop as it has nothing defined in it.

**for(initialization;condition;increment/decrements);** is called `dummy for loop`.

It works as:

';' have a unique identification number 0 (NULL).

When we add semicolon at the end of for loop, it acts as the body of the `for` loop. So, `for` loop will do nothing(semicolon).

1. Now if there are arguments passed in for loop, say, `(i=0;i<=10,i++);` then it will run 10 times and will do nothing.
2. If there are no arguments passed, `for( ; ; );` then it is an infinite loop and will do nothing.

It is called "dummy" because of semicolon as it does nothing.

Comment: Which time-delay? As the loop will never exit, the only possible delay is **infinite**. Note that any halfway recent compiler compiler will not emit code for statements after the loop. In general using simple counting loops (not the one here!) for delays is poor design and will eventually break your program once you use interrupts.

Comment: @olaf the loop `for( ; ; );` is an infinite loop but `for(i=1;i<=10;i++);` isn't. The **time-delay** is the time which is consumed in processing of moving `i` from `1 to 10` and when it will go to `11`, the loop will exit.

try it once and you will see.

Comment: LOL! that loop will be optimized by the compiler! Even if not, it does not provide a reliable delay. The correct way is to use timers of an appropriate form.

Answer (score 0):

Given dummyloop.c

```
int main(int args, char ** pargs)
{
  for(;;);
}
```

**gcc -g -c dummyloop.c**

**objdump -d -M intel -S dummyloop.o**

```
dummyloop.o:     format de fichier elf64-x86-64


Déassemblage de la section .text:

0000000000000000 <main>:

int main(int args, char ** pargs)
{
   0:   55                      push   rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
   4:   89 7d fc                mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],edi
   7:   48 89 75 f0             mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],rsi
  for(;;);
   b:   eb fe                   jmp    b <main+0xb>
```

`b: jmp    b` is **infinite loop**

An active infinite loop is something we usualy would like to avoid.